# Iterating through lists of varied data type and which are contingent upon each other

Tags: python, list, calendar

I'm working on a personal project in Python which utilizes a customized calendar different from our own (preventing the use of Python's Calendar module). I am very new to Python, and the purpose of the application I am writing is to take the current date as input from the user, then take as input from the user the number of days which have passed since the start date, and print the new date out to the user.

Conceptually, I understand the logic I am trying to reproduce, but I am struggling to conceive of the right implementation. Currently, I have user input functional and lists against which the user input should be checked:

```
weekDay = ["day1", "day2", "day3", "day4", "day5", "day6"] #like Sunday-Saturday, but only 6 days
dayNum = [1,2,3,...,33] #shortened for brevity, I promise it's written correctly
monthName = ["month1", "month2", ..., "month12", "month13"] #again for brevity, written thus because month 13 is an exception (30 days instead of normal 33)

currentDay = input("Enter the day of the week: ")
currentNum = int(input("Enter the day of the month: "))
currentMonth = input("Enter the current month: ")        
currentYear = int(input("Enter the current year: "))
print("The starting date is:", currentDay, currentNum, currentMonth, currentYear)
daysPast = int(input("Enter the number of days which have passed since the start date: "))
sumDays = currentNum + daysPast
newDay = currentNum
```

What I am asking, in brief, is what method(s) would you recommend for a beginner like myself to correctly loop through this data?

Comment: FYI you can shorten `dayNum` to `list(range(1, 34))`

Comment: If your months have different lengths, like real months do, you can use a dictionary to map the month names to their lengths.

Comment: Then use a loop that goes through the months, subtracting the lengths from `daysPast` until it's less than the month length. For the first iteration, you only subtract the days remaining in the start month.

Comment: Please show what you've tried. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.